# How can I use `throwM` with `Except`?

Tags: haskell

There is a package [`transformers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) that features the monad [`Except`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:Except).

> This monad transformer extends a monad with the ability to throw exceptions.

There is a package [`exceptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) that features the effect [`throwM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.2/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#v:throwM).

> Throw an exception. ...

So it would seem that these two should play well together. However:

```
λ runExcept $ throwM Overflow

<interactive>:46:13: error:
    • No instance for (MonadThrow Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)
        arising from a use of ‘throwM’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘throwM Overflow’
      In the expression: runExcept $ throwM Overflow
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = runExcept $ throwM Overflo
```

I know I can use the monad [`Catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.2/docs/Control-Monad-Catch-Pure.html#t:Catch). But anyway, I would like to
understand what is going on. I am not very familiar with monad transformers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler infers types this way:

- Since `runExcept :: Except e a -> ...`, the argument of `runExcept` must be of type `Except e a`.
  So, `throwM Overflow :: Except e a`
- `Except e a` is a type synonym for `ExceptT e Identity a`.
  So, `throwM Overflow :: ExceptT e Identity a`
- Because `throwM :: MonadThrow m => e -> m a`, the compiler needs to find an instance of `ThrowM` for a type that would match `ExceptT e Identity`.
- And look: [there is such instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.2/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow): `MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ExceptT e m)`. It matches any `ExceptT e m` for any `m`, but this `m` also must have an instance of `MonadThrow`.
- Matching up the type of `throwM Overflow`, which is `ExceptT e Identity a`, and the type for which the `MonadThrow` instance is defined, which is `Except T m`, the compiler determines that `m = Identity`.
- But wait! According to the instance definition `MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ExceptT e m)`, this `m` (which we now know to be `Identity`) must also have a `MonadThrow` instance.
- So the compiler looks for that, and doesn't find it.
- And displays you an error message: *"No instance `MonadThrow Identity`"*

Type class-related error messages can be vexing. The compiler doesn't always tell you the full chain of conclusions it has followed in order to reach the error. This is unfortunate, but whatchagonnado.

But the underlying problem here is that `Except` and `throwM` *aren't actually compatible*. That is to say, `throwM` throws errors in a different sense than `Except` contains errors. They're two different error-related mechanisms. In order to throw an `Except`-compatible error, use [its own `throwE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:throwE). This should work:

```
> runExcept $ throwE Overflow
Left Overflow
```

---

As far as I understand at the moment, the error-handling landscape in Haskell hasn't yet settled down to a manageable state. We have `Except`, which got generalized to `ExceptT`, and then we have `throw`, `throwTo`, `throwIO`, `throwSTM`, `throwE`, `throwError`, `throwM`, and all of those have variants from different libraries and under different monads. Plus, the arrival of `UnliftIO` has complicated things even further. It sort of looks like `ExceptT` will be going away as a result.

Comment: I made [an issue](https://github.com/ekmett/exceptions/issues/73) asking why there is no such instance, we shall see if anything comes up.

Comment: Instance `MonadThrow Identity` cannot exist, because where would the exception go?

Comment: Surely `instance MonadThrow Except` could.